# How to use vpn in shared bridge connection

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, vpn, network-bridge

Laptop is connected to wifi. Laptop also provide internet to another machine (M1) with ethernet port using bridge connection. Now when i use VPN in laptop, it works fine but the vpn is not available to M1. Is there a way so that i can configure VPN system-wide such that M1 can also use VPN.

```
Laptop : intel i7-4th gen
OS : Ubuntu 20.04
M1 : PS5
VPN : protonvpn-cli, warp-cli (installed using cli)
```

I followed this guide to share wifi to ethernet.

```
1. Open your Settings > Network.
2. Under the Wired section, click the plus sign to create a new settings profile. 
3. Name the profile "Shared" or whatever you want.
4. In the IPv4 tab, choose "Shared to other computers". Click Apply
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: How exactly did you configure the bridge connection?

Comment: @Bodo I have updated the post.